# Use of uninitialized value $key_value in print at

Tags: perl

This is my first post. So please excuse me of any irregularities. I am newbie to Perl and I have got the following issue. I get the error "Use of uninitialized value ...at" when I use the param function in Perl. Here's the code.

```
use CGI qw(param);

print "Content-type: text/plain \n\n";

$key_value=param('sososo');

print $key_value;
```

and my html file is

```
<input type="radio" name="rate" id="sososo" value="1"/> 
<label for="sososo">so</label> <br>
```

In other words I want the value 1 to be displayed. But obviously it does not assign the value to $key_value. I don't know why. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you reading in your html file?

Comment: I have got a form line 
<form action="....cgi" method="get">

<input type="radio" name="rate" id="sososo" value="1"/> 
<label for="sososo">so</label> <br> 

other radio buttons

And at the end 

<input type="submit" value="Submit Form!">
</p>
</form>

Answer (score 4):

To get the value of an input field, you have to use the name of the element, not the id.

use

```
$key_value=param('rate');
```

instead of

```
$key_value=param('sososo');
```

Comment: Of course, there's still nothing to prevent an inquisitive visitor from trying to see what will happen if your script receives a `GET` request without this parameter. Code defensively.

Comment: @tripleee: you're right. This is just to resolved the first OP's problem.